# Determining uninstaller directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to determine the directory of the uninstaller for a particular software. I can retrieve the full path using the following:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Adobe Flash Player Plugin" | findstr "UninstallString"
```

which gives:

```
UninstallString     REG_SZ  C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\FlashUtil11g_Plugin.exe -maintain plugin
```

Now, how would I get the directory where the uninstaller is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:  It depends on the format that you've shown

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Adobe Flash Player Plugin" ^| findstr "UninstallString" ') do echo "%%~dpa"
```